# How to get svg path element's facing degree in Jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

I have a svg map that have many path elements that all look similar. I want to get their x axis, y axis and angle (transform / rotation / degrees) positions for other manipulations.

Using getBBox i can able to get x axis and y axis. but i want to get the rotation angle of the path element (i.e., something like 180 degree, 320 degree etc..). Is there any way i can get the path elements angle.

please check the fiddle below in which i can retrieve x axis and y axis but not angle.

http://jsfiddle.net/YKMwf/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bb = $('#svg_3').get(0).getBBox();
     $("#divaxis1").html("x = " + bb.x + "  y = " + bb.y);

    bb = $('#svg_2').get(0).getBBox();
     $("#divaxis2").html("x = " + bb.x + "  y = " + bb.y);
});
```

Comment: Neither of the paths in your fiddle are rotated.

Comment: okay i got it now. it is drawn like that and not rotated..... :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track and change the rotation of an element - this is best done in CSS. You can then proceed to track the angular position.

http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Comment: my objective is to fetch the angle of the path elements from exisitng SVG. And then draw the path elements on flash application using the x,y,angles. there is no space for css here.

Comment: The problem is the svg does not include information of it's rotation. It's literally drawn to that angle, opposed to it being drawn straight and then transformed.